# IndentationError: unexpected indent - Python 3

Tags: indentation

Consider:

```python
for row in newRows:
    # If key is not in the data dictionary, we skip it
    key = int(row[ID_idx]) #key = ID
    if not key in dct:
        continue

    # Initialise other variables
    b_date = str2date(row[b_date_idx], give_default_begin=True) # Beginning of event
    e_date = str2date(row[e_date_idx], give_default_end=True) # Ending of event
    b_reg = dct[key]['CRC_dates'][3] # Beginning of registration
    e_reg = dct[key]['CRC_dates'][4] # Ending of registration

    original_code = row[code_idx]
    if original_code == None: # Skip it
        continue
    truncated_code = self.generate_code(original_code, limit) #adjust code so that it is correct
    if truncated_code == None: #skip it
        continue
    if suffix == 'lab_results':
        val, min_val, max_val = self.make_lab_values(row[val_idx], row[min_idx], row[max_idx])
        if val == '': #skip it
            continue
```

This is a part of a class I have written. When I run the script, I get the following error:

> IndentationError: unexpected indent.

It refers to the line in where I say "for row in newRows:". However, I have made all tabs/spaces visible in my text editor and cannot find any problems with indentation. What is the reason?

Comment: seems the code above this line does not support spaces before the line *for row in newRows:*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I solved the problem; the indentation of the lines above 'for row in newRows' were wrong. However, because those lines were commented, I had no idea that could cause a problem!

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged with Python?